# Ajax call to spring boot controller to redirecting a view

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new to spring boot framework. 
I have a jQuery method that gets called upon the click of a span element. In that jQuery method, I have an ajax call which makes a call to the spring boot controller and passes a string as a parameter. The controller is getting the parameter passed from the ajax call. But it is not redirecting to a different view. The different view is an html page called **ajaxView.html**. I want to add an attribute to the view as well. Any help would be great.

Here's my ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.spanClass').on('click', '#id_1', function(event){   
     event.stopPropagation();

         var str = ((event.target.parentElement).parentElement.href);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "http://localhost:8080//span/view?term="+encodeURIComponent(str),
                contentType: 'text/plain',
                crossDomain: false,
                async:true,
                success:function(response) {        
                }
            });
  });
});
```

Here's my controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value = "/span/view")
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView redirectAjax(String term, Model model) {

    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setName(term);

    model.addAttribute("employee", emp);

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/ajaxView");

}
```

Comment: You can't redirect from AJAX to different PAGE. You need to handle it via Script only. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346430/performing-a-normal-redirect-from-an-ajax-spring-mvc-controller-method?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

you need to call a controller again form your Ajax success function to open the **ajaxView.html** page for you. :--

**1.) your ajax Call should be like this :--**

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "http://localhost:8080//span/view?term="+encodeURIComponent(str),
                contentType: 'text/plain',
                crossDomain: false,
                async:true,
                success:function(response) {  

                window.location = '/yourAjaxControllerName';
                }
            });
```

**2.) Your controller :--**

```
   @RequestMapping("/yourAjaxControllerName")
    public String getAjaxViewPage(HttpServletRequest request,Model model) {

       return "ajaxView";

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in Ajax itself.

In success method of Ajax call you need to resent the response.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.spanClass').on('click', '#id_1', function(event){   
     event.stopPropagation();

         var str = ((event.target.parentElement).parentElement.href);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "http://localhost:8080//span/view?term="+encodeURIComponent(str),
                contentType: 'text/plain',
                crossDomain: false,
                async:true,
                success:function(emp) {     
                  alert(emp);  
                  window.location.href = '/JspControllerHandler?employee='+ JSON.stringify(emp); // redirect     //this would be GET
                }
            });
  });
});
```

Your controller will return Employee data to requesting Ajax.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value = "/span/view")
public @ResponseBody Employee redirectAjax(String term, Model model) {
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    emp.setName(term);
    return emp;
}
```

You Ajax will have responsibly to redirect to another page

```
  @RequestMapping("/JspControllerHandler")
    public String redirectJsp(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam("employee") String empStr) {
    Employee employee = null;
    try
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        employee = mapper.readValue(empStr, Employee.class);
         model.addAttribute("employee", employee );
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Error while converting JSON string to employee object.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
       return "jspView";
     }
```

Comment: Awesome! But how can you access the variable "emp" passed from window.location.href = '/JspControllerHandler?employee='+ emp; in the controller, redirectJsp ? I got null value when I tried to access emp properties. FYI emp properties in the ajax is not null.

Comment: @khalbali Code Updated . try now

Comment: It doesn't work. emp is an object. And I want to preserve it as an object than convert it to a string. I intend to pass that object to the jspView.html page as a model attribute.

Comment: @khalibali Code is updated. Thing is you need to convert that JSON to Object and pass to spring model